# Why a private event handler does not work in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Here is the issue:

I have a simple ASP.NET form with 2 buttons.

One of them is created by dragging the button from the tools and the other I created directly in HTML:

```
<body>
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <asp:Button OnClick="ABC" Runat="server" Text="rrr" id="Button1"></asp:Button>
    <asp:Button  id="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button"></asp:Button>
</form>
</body>
```

Button2 is created using tools and has the following Event Handler:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim s As String = ""
 End Sub
```

This "Private Event handler runs without any problem.

However for the button which is created under HTML , we have the following event handler:

```
Private Sub ABC(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim a As Integer = 0

End Sub
```

For this one I get the following complile error:

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30390: 'WebApplication9.WebForm1.Private Sub ABC(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Private'.
```

If I change the event handler scope from Private to protected this will work. Question is why private works for one event handler but not the other one.

Comment: Having `OnClick` **and** `Handles` means you're trying to hook it up twice - once from the code behind, and once from the HTML. If you switch to `Protected`, you'll find that the event handler is invoked twice (as you currently have it). Remove the `OnClick` in the HTML

Comment: I just tried to add "Hanldes" after I saw the compile error. I get same compile error with or without the Handler keyword.

Comment: I said remove the `OnClick` in the HTML, not the `Handles`.

Comment: This situation is very simple to replicate. Anyone can setup and replicate the above scenario in 2 minutes.

Comment: If I remove the OnClick  then, it is like I have dragged 2 button to my form from the toolbox(codewise). I wanted to know why one of these works with private and otherone needs Protected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, an aspx page is implemented as *two* classes. One of these classes contains your code behind code (`.aspx.vb`) (and, depending on which version/model of ASP.Net you're using, also some designer generated code (`.aspx.designer.vb`)).

The second class is created when the page is first requested (or the site is pre-compiled) and contains any inline code from the `.aspx` page and other code generated by ASP.Net, and includes e.g. code for any controls declared with `runat="server"`.

This second class inherits from the first.

So, if the *first* class takes responsibility for hooking up its event handlers, it uses a [`Handles` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y.aspx)*:

```
Private Sub ABC(...) Handles Button1.Click
```

`Button1` belongs to this class because it was put there by the designer generated code. Everything is local to this class, and so the method can be `Private`.

If the *second* class takes responsibility for hooking up an event handler, it does it by using attributes on server controls, such as here:

```
<asp:Button OnClick="ABC" Runat="server"
```

Now, unless `ABC` is a method declared inline inside the `.aspx` file, it has to be from the *first* class (or any class from which the *first* itself inherits from)

We now have a situation where code in the *second* class wants to refer to code in the *first* class. And so, the rules of .NET say that the member that it's trying to access cannot be `Private`.

---

What you shouldn't have, as you have in your question, is *both* classes taking responsibility for hooking up the (same) event handlers.

---

*It doesn't *have* to use a `Handles` clause - it could also set up the event handler using [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inside e.g. the `Page_Load` event, or anywhere else that's appropriate. `Handles` is idiomatic for static controls on a page in VB. In C#, there's no equivalent to `Handles`, so the event handlers are hooked up with C#'s equivalent of `AddHandler`, `+=`.

Comment: Good explanation but not everything declared is privated:
Button1 itself is declared as Protected:
Protected WithEvents Button1 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button